# how can i convert a RTF document to docx

Tags: powershell

I have found something similar on [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-Word-documents-5ccc1067) but when I try running this I get errors.
I was therfore wondering if it would be possible to make a Powershell script that can take .RTF documents and convert them all to .docx documents?

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/8db50747-9e71-4116-9214-32787bd33d2b

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert rtf to docx:

```
Function Convert-Dir($path){
    $Files=Get-ChildItem "$($path)\*.docx" -Recurse
    $Word=New-Object –ComObject WORD.APPLICATION

    foreach ($File in $Files) {
        # open a Word document, filename from the directory
        $Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname)

        # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename
        $Name=($Doc.Fullname).replace("docx","doc")

        if (Test-Path $Name){

        } else {
            # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
            Write-Host $Name
            $Doc.saveas([ref] $Name, [ref] 0)  
            $Doc.close()
        }
    }

    $Files=Get-ChildItem "$($path)\*.rtf" -Recurse
    $Word=New-Object –ComObject WORD.APPLICATION

    foreach ($File in $Files) {
        # open a Word document, filename from the directory
        $Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname)

        # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename
        $Name=($Doc.Fullname).replace("rtf","doc")

        if (Test-Path $Name){

        } else {
            # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
            Write-Host $Name
            $Doc.saveas([ref] $Name, [ref] 0)  
            $Doc.close()
        }
    }
}

Convert-Dir "RtfFilePath";
```

Code from and attribution: https://gist.github.com/rensatsu/0a66a65c3a508ecfd491#file-rtfdocxtodoc-ps1

Comment: gives errors when i try to run it. "cannot find type word.apploication" amongst others.
are some modules maybe missing that i need to import?